# Библиотека Zxing генерирует лишние отступы вокруг QR-кода

Tags: java, qrcode, zxing

При использовании библиотеки Zxing генерируются лишние отступы, хотя размеры QR-кодов одинаковые (200 на 200) и явно задан MARGIN = 0.

На приведенных рисунках разное количество данных при создании кода. На первых двух QR-код полностью заполнил пространство, а на последнем остались белые отступы. Почему такое может быть?

[image: Нормальное масштабирование]
[image: Нормальное масштабирование]
[image: Ненормальное масштабирование]

Код:

```java
final int width = 200;
final int height = 200;
final Writer writer = new QRCodeWriter();
Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = new HashMap<>();
hints.put(CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");
hints.put(MARGIN, 0);
final BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(sourceValue, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height, hints);

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
int[] rgbArray = new int[width * height];
int i = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        rgbArray[i] = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? 0x000000 : 0xFFFFFF;
        i++;
    }
}
image.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, rgbArray, 0, width);

return image;
```

Зависимость maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
    <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow на русском! Не очень ясна суть вашей проблемы, [отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1317340/edit) вопрос, что вы подразумеваете под "не одинаковым масштабированием"? Разная ширина белой рамки вокруг qr-кода?

Comment: Спасибо, отредактировал

Comment: Укажите в вопросе, какие значения `width` и `height` вы используете.

Comment: И еще укажите, как подключаете библиотеку zxing ([core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core), [javase](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/javase)?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотека [zxing](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core) при формировании `BitMatrix` увеличивает матрицу QR-кода в *кратное* число раз, чтобы заполнить пространство `width × height`. Поэтому, по краям могут остаться пустоты.

Чтобы этих пустот не было, в качестве `width` и `height` можно передать `0`, тогда на выходе мы получим `BitMatrix` минимального размера:

```java
BitMatrix matrix = writer.encode(content, QR_CODE, 0, 0);
```

Далее, `BitMatrix` можно преобразовать в `BufferedImage` с помощью [MatrixToImageWriter](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/javase):

```java
BufferedImage image = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(matrix)
```

Мы получили картинку минимального размера, дальше, пользуясь инструментами `awt`, можно [увеличить](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35637914) размер картинки до необходимых размеров.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!